# Services 3 Output alter hook

Tags: hooks, services, 8

Are there any [hooks](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/7) to alter the [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) modules output. 
For eg : If I get a result like this for a file object.

```
{
  "fid": "132",
  "uri": "public:\/\/512dab4918036.jpg",
  "filename": "512dab4918036.jpg",
  "filemime": "image\/jpeg",
  "uid": "1",
  "status": 1,
  "timestamp": 1361947464,
  "filesize": 2521,
}
```

I want to limit it for users with certain roles.

I am looking for this as I have made many services resource manually so I don't want to edit them all and simply use the output alter hook to do something.

Is it possible ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do ? Remove some of the fields in the file object ?

Comment: @drcelus no i want to deliver a default output if user dont met certain criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The available hooks for Services are documented in the [api docs for services](http://drupalcode.org/project/services.git/tree/refs/heads/7.x-3.x:/docs)

You probably want [`hook_services_request_postprocess_alter($controller, $args, $result);`](http://dev.drupalcontrib.org/api/services/docs!services.alter.api.php/function/hook_services_request_postprocess_alter/7.x-3.x) which allows you to change the array of $result any way you want.

Comment: may i know how to use "hook_services_request_postprocess_alter" .I have field called 'body' in $result ,I want to wrap it with CDATA.Any idea how to do it? &$result[0]->body is my variable

Comment: I assume you mean you don't know how to implement a hook? If you have a module named mymodule, you would implement a function called mymodule_services_request_postprocess_alter() with the arguments described above. More on Drupal's (pretty weird) hook system is at https://www.drupal.org/node/292